# Guess what is described here

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Bury me deep, pile on every stone.
Yet in the end I will dig up every bone.

I can make you feel hurt or make you smile,
Accepting me will sometimes take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer:

> A memory perhaps.

Bury me deep, pile on every stone.
Yet in the end I will dig up every bone.

> Trying to repress a memory, but it just won't fully go away.

I can make you feel hurt or make you smile,
Accepting me will sometimes take a while.

> A memory can bring out these feelings. Being at peace with a memory can sometimes take some time.

Answer (score 0):

> DEATH

Bury me deep, pile on every stone.

> Sounds like they are burying someone.

Yet in the end I will dig up every bone.

> Like the saying of bones to pick, not specifically in a bad way though.

I can make you feel hurt or make you smile,

> Memories can hurt or be happy.

Accepting me will sometimes take a while.

> Accepting that they died.

Comment: Death can make you smile?

Comment: i meant as in the memories you had with them

Comment: sorry should have been clearer